# What's the right way to disconnect a MediaController?

Tags: android

What's the right way to shut down a `MediaController` with an attached `MediaPlayer`?

You can't do `mediaController.setMediaPlayer(null)` - that immediately calls updatePausePlay, which dereferences the null.

You can't call `mediaPlayer.release()`, since MediaController is going to call MediaPlayer#getCurrentPosition, and that throws an IllegalStateException after `release()` has been called.

Comment: try calling `mediaPlayer.reset()` before `mediaPlayer.release()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the below snippet, in this order

```
mediaController.hide();
mediaPlayer.stop();
mediaPlayer.release();
```

Comment: But _why_ do you think this is the right way to stop it, not just something that works now and will fail next week?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this but here's my guess as to why its the right way.  `mediaController.hide()` stops the mediaController from being displayed and thus from querying the `mediaPlayer`.  Once it is not querying the `mediaPlayer` any more you can shut it down by stopping it then releasing it (you might not need to stop it first, haven't tried).  I don't really see any way that this could fail in the future unless you try to start using the same mediaController again after you have released the mediaPlayer without pointing it to something new. This seems proper to me.